# Apollo client stopPolling not working after package bump

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm trying to update my version of @apollo/client from `3.7.1` to `3.9.3` but am having an issue with any query that uses `startPolling` and `stopPolling`.

After upgrade, `stopPolling` never fires correctly, causing polling to run continuously. Since I have actions that rely on polling having finished, this breaks my app.

Below is an example of one of these queries

```
export function useMyPolledQuery({
  additionalOnCompleted,
  skip,
  variables,
  fetchPolicy = 'cache-and-network',
}: Type) {
  const { startPolling, stopPolling, ...queryResult } =
    useMyPolledQuery({
      skip,
      variables,
      onCompleted(data) {
        additionalOnCompleted?.(data);
        const result = data?.myData;
        if (result?.status !== myData.Loading) {
          return stopPolling();
        }
        startPolling(1000);
      },
      onError(error) {
        Sentry.captureException(error);
        stopPolling();
      },
      fetchPolicy,
    });

  return queryResult;
}
```

I found [this issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/7221) but nothing suggested here resolves the issue. I've also tried using an explicit work around by using `pollInterval` and a state setter, something like

```
export function useMyPolledQuery({
  additionalOnCompleted,
  skip,
  variables,
  fetchPolicy = 'cache-and-network',
}: Type) {
  const [ stopPolling, setStopPolling ] = useState(false)

  const { ...queryResult } =
    useMyPolledQuery({
      skip,
      variables,
      onCompleted(data) {
        additionalOnCompleted?.(data);
        const result = data?.myData;
        if (result?.status !== myData.Loading) {
          return stopPolling();
        }
        startPolling(1000);
      },
      onError(error) {
        Sentry.captureException(error);
        stopPolling();
      },
      fetchPolicy,
      pollInterval: stopPolling ? 0 : 1000 
    });

  return queryResult;
```

But this doesn't work either. Does anyone have any suggestions? There's nothing in the documentation to suggest this wouldn't work after package bump.

Comment: Hey there, Apollo Client maintainer here. Would you mind opening an issue in the Apollo Client repo? This looks like a bug and we'd like to track this. Any reproduction you can provide us would be super helpful.

Comment: @jerelmiller I'll update my question here, but the solution here was to use `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true`. The issue was caused by calling the `stopPolling` within the onComplete, which would never trigger without this flag. LMK if this is intended behaviour (it's not documented) and I can open an issue for either documentation, or to fix the bug.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. 3.8 changed the behavior of when onCompleted fires, so that would explain it. You can see more info in this PR: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/pull/10229.

We have an issue to provide better documentation here but haven't had a chance to finish it yet. Follow here for more updates on that. https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/11306

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who comes across this, the issue is caused by calling `stopPolling` within onComplete, without passing a flag of `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true`.

In previous versions this worked, but now you need to use this option if you want your onComplete to control polling.

Comment: You are my hero, thanks @Muskett